# Regex for words containing letters in alphabetic order JAVA

Tags: java, regex

My student(high school) asked me a question about regex matching a word which contains letters in alphabetic order. To be honest I do not know how to create regex such that.
Example of words matching, size of letters does not matter:

```
abc, aWZ, gOR, bor
```

Comment: You could write a very long one (1,000+ characters) that checks every possible character ordering...

Comment: There may be a shorter way, but all I can come up with (in the regex field) is `a*b*c*d*e*...` etc.

Comment: @BrianAgnew And lose the learning experience of doing it by hand!? Never!

Comment: Regex are not very well suited for that kind of operation and `char[] sorted = s.toCharArray(); Arrays.sort(sorted); boolean matches = Arrays.equals(s.toCharArray(), sorted);` seems more convenient (in lower case if necessary)...

Comment: @assylias That would be a very good solution (except `sort` is a void method).

Comment: @assylias Your solution is easier, but in this case I think regex could be faster/more efficient

Comment: Another regexless approach is to just iterate the chars, ensuring `s[i+1] >= s[i]`.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard If performance is an issue: `for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) if(s.charAt(i) < s.charAt(i-1)) return false; return true;`

Comment: @assylias do either of your solutions account for case insensitivty? aAbc is valid given the restrictions laid out in the question, but it might get turned into Aabc by `sort`

Comment: @PeterElliott It's not a big deal to just normalize to single case before the procedure.

Comment: @assylias We need to stop writing identical replies (it's probably me who should stop :)

Comment: @assylias well, Marko's answer actually accounts for case sensitivty (with the i flag)... seems like it would be clearer to propose code that actually answers the question as stated (which is case-insensitive), to avoid confusion

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Although technically I am the one that comes second by a few seconds each time!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
^a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*$
```

should work

Comment: Wait, why didn't we think of this!?  We'd need to include caps, but otherwise I cannot think of why this would have a problem.

Comment: @BlackVegetable just make the regex case insensitive with the `i` flag, and you don't need to worry about caps

Comment: Doh! I didn't know that was how that worked.  That's why I didn't upvote the other answer sooner.

Comment: but it will also match words like `acer`, because these letters go alphabetically in right direction but not one after another

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```
(?i)a*b*c*...z*
```

It would be easy to construct in a loop.

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(64);
b.append("(?i)");
for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++) b.append((char)i).append('*');
return Pattern.compile(b.toString()).matcher(input).matches();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not really a good problem for a regex, it's almost certainly easier to check it in  a for loop:

```
import static java.lang.Character.isLetter;
import static java.lang.Character.toLowerCase;

public boolean alphabeticalOrder(String word) {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (!isLetter(word.charAt(i)) || 
                toLowerCase(word.charAt(i + 1)) < toLowerCase(word.charAt(i)))
            return false;
    }
    return isLetter(word.charAt(word.length() - 1));
}
```

Alternatively, the following regex will also match correctly (for ASCII alphabetic characters only) when passing in the [`CASE_INSENSITIVE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE):

```
^a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*$
```

Comment: you need to put the word in upper or lower case for you algo to work (otherwise 'Z' < 'a' will return true for example)

Comment: @assylias You are completely correct, my memory of ascii told me that capitals came after lower-case, I'll modify my code to be correct right now.

Comment: Note: you can remove `!isLetter(word.charAt(i + 1)`: you will test it at the next iteration anyhow.

Comment: @assylias I left it in order to ensure we check `word.length() - 1`, although it may be more terse to add it at the end like I had before, I'll update it.