# Check for Alphabetical Order in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a Regex that will pass all strings that are in alphabetical order, (i.e. "ABC", "AABC", "AABBC", "ACDZ")

But, they should not pass strings that *at any point* go in reverse alphabetical order, (i.e. "ABA", "ABCDEFA")

I've tried looking up online what I could do, but I can't find anything yet.

Thanks in advance for the help,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for words containing letters in alphabetic order JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343273/regex-for-words-containing-letters-in-alphabetic-order-java)

Comment: It may be for a different language, but the regex would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is `regex` will work for your problem.

```
^a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*$
```

Try this is for both `uppercase` and `lowercase` letter:

```
^[a|A]*[b|B]*[c|C]*[d|D]*[e|E]*[f|F]*[g|G]*[h|H]*[i|I]*[j|J]*[k|K]*[l|L]*[m|M]*[n|N]*[o|O]*[p|P]*[q|Q]*[r|R]*[s|S]*[t|T]*[u|U]*[v|V]*[w|W]*[x|X]*[y|Y]*[z|Z]*$
```